# Pagination in thesis framework wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I create a shortcode for blogpost and create function in custom_function.php.
here is my code

```
add_shortcode('blogPost',blogpost);
function blogpost(){ 
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$archive_project = new WP_query(); $archive_project->query('cat=9&posts_per_page=9&paged='.$paged ); ?>
while ($archive_project->have_posts()) : $archive_project->the_post();
// my display code.
endwhile;
```

This run successfully but I fail to create pagination in it.
kindly resolve my issue in thesis framework in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/setup-plugin-wp-pagenavi-for-thesis-2x?replies=3

The example you posted is for blogspot not WordPress nor thesis.